# Why is my VowelCount function not returning the proper solution?

Tags: javascript, foreach

For some reason, VowelCount() only counts one vowel in the case where there is a pair of adjacent vowels. For example, it counts "oe" in "goes" as one vowel. I don't understand why this is happening. It does this regardless of whether I use the forEach function or a for loop. Can anyone clear up my misunderstanding?

Here is my code:

```js
function VowelCount(str) { 
  var charArr = str.split('');
  var pattern = /[aeiou]/gi;
  var vowelCount = 0;
  /*
  charArr.forEach(function(char) {
    if (pattern.test(char)) {
        //console.log(char);
        vowelCount++;
    }
  }); 
  */
  for (var i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
    //console.log(charArr[i]);
    if (pattern.test(charArr[i])) vowelCount++;
  }
  return vowelCount;              
}   

console.log(VowelCount("goes"));
```

Comment: According to [`.test()` method doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), *"as with `exec()` (or in combination with it), `test()` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match."* So removing the `g` fixes your problem, as would creating a new regex object on each iteration of the loop by doing `if (/[aeiou]/gi.test(charArr[i]))...`

Comment: P.S. `return (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length` will give you the vowel count without any need for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but the global search `/g` is causing it to fail on the `e`. You don't need the global search as you're checking against individual characters anyway.

Here is a working version:

```
function VowelCount(str) { 
    var pattern = /[aeiou]/i;
    var vowelCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (pattern.test(str[i])){
            vowelCount++;
        }
    }
    return vowelCount; 
}

console.log(VowelCount("goes")); //2
```

I also changed it so that you don't need to turn it into a char array. Foreaching over the string achieves the same end.

Comment: You are correct about removing the "g" flag. When using g, the regex will maintain a property called lastIndex, which gets advanced and is not reset until a false result happens.

Comment: @jeffcarey that's useful to know - I do very little with regex and that would have definitely tripped me up if I was OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
function VowelCount(subject) {
    console.log(subject.match(/[aeiou]/gi));
    // or to get the length 
    console.log(subject.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length);
}

VowelCount("goes");
//result -> ["o", "e"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the number of vowels using your pattern and the `match()` function. This way you don't need to loop through an array and you get your count if it matches:

```
var chars = 'fred is a flintstone';
var pattern = /[aeiou/gi;
var matches = chars.match(pattern);
var vowelCount = matches ? matches.length : 0;
```

Comment: Or as I commented above, you can do it in one line: `return (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi)||[]).length`...

Comment: hmm yea that's a bit slicker, though I tend to try and spell things out a bit more for OP's to show the steps (yea admittedly i did use a ternary without explanation). Didn't see your comment before I posted.